# Stability analysis of Numerical Method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

For a system of ODEs, I'm looking at the case where $$u'=Au$$ where $A$ is diagonalisable so $$u'=R\Lambda R^{-1}u.$$ In the notes I am looking at it goes on to say we can premultiply by $R^{-1}$ so $$ R^{-1}u'=\Lambda R^{-1}u$$ and then let $v(t)=R^{-1}u(t)$ such that $$v'=\Lambda v.$$ I can see this is a decoupled system of scalar equations for each component of $v$. I think from here you can apply the scheme you are looking at and investigate stability, but I am not sure why this arises from that rearrangement and substitution. Any pointers appreciated - it doesn't seem clear to me in the notes I am looking at.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The way this question is written, I cannot tell what you are looking for.

Comment: Basically, why make the transformation from $u'=Au$ to $v'=\Lambda v$ to investigate the absolute stability of a numerical scheme for a system of equations. I'm looking at http://www.siam.org/books/ot98/sample/OT98Chapter7.pdf 7.4.2. if that's a help.

Comment: Because $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix, so it's eigenvalues are simply the diagonal, or in other words, the solution
$$v(t) = c\exp(\Lambda t)$$
Has the very simple form
$$(v(t))_i = c \exp(\lambda_{ii}t)$$
So it's growth can be read off $\Lambda$ directly.

Comment: So provided all the eigenvalues are negative it is stable?

Comment: Depending on your definition of stability, yes. Eigenvalues (=diagonal entries of $\Lambda$) $<0$ mean that initial errors are decaying (contracted), so the solutions of the ODE to perturbed initial conditions converge towards each other.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Happy to help. I'll compile this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason we want to investigate $\Lambda$ is because the stability of the general solution
$$u(t) = u_0 \exp(At)$$
only depends on the eigenvalues of $A$ (and not their corresponding eigenvectors). Thus the ODEs for $u$ and $v$ have the same stability. Now note that
$$(v(t))_i = (v_0 \exp(\Lambda t))_i = v_0 \exp(\lambda_{ii} t)$$
So the solutions of perturbed initial conditions converge iff $\lambda_{ii}<0\ \forall\ i$.

Comment: Hi Alex, could I point you towards a question I have just asked if you wouldn't mind - it is sort of a follow on from this but I didn't want to edit the question. Thanks :)

Comment: @BritMiller I have taken a look and provided an answer. I hope it was useful :)